# How do you filter packets differently based on time of day in nftables?

Tags: nftables

I would like to e.g. block certain traffic between 00:00 and 04:00. Is this possible in nftables?

(Obviously I can just set a cron job that changes the config at these times - but I would like to know if there is a nftables "native" way of achieving this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are recent patches allowing to do just that, but they are not yet available in any release.

Here are the relevant patches (but they are part of series, they would probably not be enough te be applied by themselves).

linux kernel:
[[v5,2/2] netfilter: nft_meta: support for time matching](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/1148703/)

[*libnftnl*](https://git.netfilter.org/libnftnl/) (userland low level nftables library):
[[libnftnl,v2,1/2] expr: meta: Make NFT_META_TIME_{NS,DAY,HOUR} known](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/1148714/)

[*nftables*](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/) (userland command):
[[nft,2/4] meta: Introduce new conditions 'time', 'day' and 'hour'](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/1155281/)

> Some usage examples:
>
> ```
>   time < "2019-06-06 17:00" drop;
>   time < "2019-06-06 17:20:20" drop;
>   time < 12341234 drop;
>   day "Saturday" drop;
>   day 6 drop;
>   hour >= 17:00 drop;
>   hour >= "17:00:01" drop;
>   hour >= 63000 drop;
> ```
>
> [...]
>   We swap left and right values in a range to properly handle cross-day
>   hour ranges (e.g. 23:15-03:22).

While the kernel patch was submitted on 2019-08-17, it had to go through [nf-next](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/pablo/nf-next.git/log/?qt=range&q=63d10e12b00dfc8d8387bea9eaab376881335731), [net-next](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/net-next.git/commit/?id=b8f6a0eeb9b99f5f0df7ee34d775b9a3a63b53a3) and was [merged for 5.4-rc1](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?h=v5.4-rc1&id=81160dda9a7aad13c04e78bb2cfd3c4630e3afab)
 on 2019-09-18. Kernel 5.4 should probably be out in a few weeks.

So according to the example above, while I couldn't test it yet, this should probably be a method to drop incoming connections to the local mail server between 00:00 and 04:00, once running with kernel 5.4, libnftnl 1.1.5? and nftables 0.9.3?:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        tcp dport 25 hour 00:00-04:00 drop
    }
}
```

Comment: Is something like this `(timestamp / 1800) mod 2` in nftables possible, i.e. to produce values `0` and `1` alternating every half hour?

Comment: @Mvorisek I don't think this is implemented. mod is available only with numgen. And there's no division available anywhere. You can still use 48 rules or find a cleaner way using sets, maybe.

Comment: I'd be interest in something as suggestedby @mvorisek, too - any updates?

Comment: @xeruf workaround in this answer of mine (to mvorisek) there: https://serverfault.com/questions/996037/nftables-timestamp-map

Comment: It seems this is now included in mainline and the nftables wifi has been updated to show the new options here: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Matching_packet_metainformation#Matching_by_time